# how to add watermark ffmpeg custom duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

I'd like to ask,

how to add a watermark in ffmpeg at a certain duration? for example I have a 2 minute video, I want the watermark to appear at 1:15 - 1:25 how to do it?

Comment: please don't repeat questions... you asked this yesterday tagging v14.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417447/how-to-add-watermark-with-ffmpeg-custom-position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add watermark with ffmpeg custom position?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417447/how-to-add-watermark-with-ffmpeg-custom-position)

Comment: @24601 not it's not a duplicate beacuse the question got deleted

Comment: kindly [edit] your question with the version of ubuntu